# SSRS how to display parameter in heading when no rows are returned

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to build a base report that has 3 parameters representing different types of services for which I am displaying all the companies and their details that match those parameters in a tablix under each Textbox heading.

The problem is that I am displaying the value of selected parameter in each heading using the expression:

="SERVICE1:  " & First(Fields!Service1.Value, "dsServices")

When the DataSet resultset returns no rows, the *parameter part* of the heading is empty but when row are returned, the heading is as I want it (ex: "SERVICE1: Some sub service category here"). I want the full heading to show up even if  there are no rows to display.  **How do I retain all of the heading?**  for the record I am using NoRowsMessage property when I want the tablix to be hidden due to no rows returned.  Again, I still want the headings with the values selected to appear.

I googled to no avail.  Thank you for any tip you can suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your heading is empty, when your dataset returns nothing is because in your expression you are referencing the first record in your "dsServices" dataset.

This is what your expression does : ="SERVICE1: " & First(Fields!Service1.Value, "dsServices")

In your question you mention you have 3 parameters...if you want to reference these parameters then rather include the parameter value in the expression. That expression would like something like this:

="SERVICE1: " & Parameters!Service1.Value)

I'm obviously assuming you have a parameter for each service type. If you do this then your expression no longer becomes dependent on your dataset.

Comment: Oh I get it! But I do have a question - my 3 parameters are Integer data types although in the parameter selection dropdown the actual name shows. Do I need to create internal parameters to represent the string name value that I want to display in the headings? When I tryed your suggestion (THANK YOU) I get the number value.

Comment: Never mind, I looked at the parameters properties (Available Values) and noted that the "Label" field is what is displayed so I changed the Expression to ="SERVICE1: " &Parameters!Service1.Label and it works.  Thanks again.

Comment: awesome. I see you have found out how to set labels and values. I wasn't quite sure if you had set those when you created your parameters so i didn't mention it. Glad to have helped.